# Is there a way to get all location point (lat and lon) around a specific country?

Tags: android, geolocation, coordinates

I'm working on an Android project which need to check if a location point is in a country (Belgium for example). The country can look like a circle, square or a polygon.

I know that it has a free Google Geocoding API via a HTTP REST API which allow to locate a point in a city or a country but it has usage limits.

I already get an algorithm to verify whether or not a point is inside an area.

**So the question is the way to get all location point around a specific country?**

Comment: Can you please tell how to find algorithm to verify whether or not point is inside an define area?

Comment: @Raj008, I used this [project](https://github.com/13kz/polygon-contains-point) to check whether or not the point is inside a polygon. Hope this will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading lot of thread, I discover GeoJSON which is a format for encoding a variety of geographic data structures. GeoJSON supports the following geometry types: Point, LineString, Polygon, MultiPoint, MultiLineString, and MultiPolygon. **AWESOME**

I finally find out a way to get location coordinates around a country (not all) by using **Umap Open Street Map** 
Umap allows to create a map with OpenStreetMap layers, draw a geometry and export data as geojson format.

Below an Example of a geojson format

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
 {
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [[lat, lon],...]
  .....}..
```